# Return to line with intro.js

Tags: javascript, intro.js

I'm wondering if it's possible with intro.js to return to the next line.
I tried the \n and other stuff like that but any of them work and impossible to find something like that in the docs.
Did anyone know if it's possible or not ?

```
<div class="pictos_menu" data-intro="You can find here the different elements.
                                      -first step
                                      -add chapter
                                      -invitations
                                      " data-step='4'>
```

Comment: This text will render as html. Use `<br/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use 
 like that:

```
<div class="pictos_menu" data-intro="You can find here the different elements.<br/>
                                  -first step<br/>
                                  -add chapter<br/>
                                  -invitations<br/>
                                  " data-step='4'>
```

Comment: can write on the same line too.